# MySQL REPLACE on JOIN

Tags: mysql, replace

I have two tables. In one, I have a part number as 123456-12. In the other, I have it as 123456x12. How can I execute something like the following.

```
LEFT JOIN qty ON REPLACE(items.item_number, '+', 'x') = qty.item_number
```

P.S. I'm just working on an app for someone and do not want to change the way their other code works.

Comment: Can you provide a databaseschema?

Comment: What isn't working in your query ?

Comment: REPLACE(items.item_number, '+', 'x'). If I remove that and replace it with items.item_number = qty.item_number, it works